# Why BizTalk server is not supporting more than one send location for one send port?

Tags: biztalk

In BizTalk server we can configure many receive locations for one receive port . In the same way if I want to send the same message to many destinations I have to create a send group containing the collection of send ports which will send the message to my desired locations . This is fine I have understood the concept of send group . But why one send port is not supporting more than one send location ??

Answer (score 2):

> But why one send port is not supporting more than one send location

I guess the main reason for this is "Because it is what it is". The difference between send port groups with multiple ports, and recieve ports with mutliple locations is mainly semantics, rather than any technical difference.

However, in the interests of argument, I *could* argue that a send port, which is by it's nature a subscriber in BizTalk, should only do a single thing. In this case that thing is to send to one transport channel (and one backup channel). If you introduced multiple "send locations" then the send port would be responsible for more than one thing.

Furthermore, the introduction of send locations would introduce complexity:

- what send locations would be invoked to send the message? Would it be the same each time?
- how to handle a mixture of synchronous and asynchronous transports on a single send port?
- etc...